# Create report base one number of records dynamically in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Let's say I have the following data:

[image]

In my SSRS report I have a parameter that prompts for MainID.
[image]

Now If I put MainID as 1, I should get one report.  If I put MainID as 6, I should get 3 reports.  Is there a way I can generate these reports dynamically using SSRS?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this by creating a report that uses a List control, and has a page break between each item that you use to group by within that List. One report, a different page for each item of interest, `SubID` in this case.

1. Create a new report with an empty body.
2. Add the Data Source(s), Parameter(s), and Dataset(s) that are needed.
3. Add a List object to the body. Drag and drop it into the body from the Toolbox.
4. Set the Dataset for the list to the one you are using to return the data you have listed in your question.
5. In the Row Groups pane of the Visual Studio report designer, right click on the Details row, and choose Group Properties. On the General page, click the Add button under Group expressions, choose `SubID` from the Group on dropdown.
6. While in the same dialog, go to the Page Breaks page and check the Between each instance of a group option. Click OK.
7. Add a Tablix inside the List. This is what will show your data.
8. Add some fields to the Tablix. Add Detail and Notes, for no good reason on my part.
9. Run the report. If you have setup the data source and data set to properly run and filter base on your parameters, you should see something. Maybe an empty report.

Now (based on the data you provided), if you choose 1 for your `MainID` parameter, the report will display one page, but if you choose 6, you will get 3 page3, or however many records there are related to the parameter value for `MainID` in the database.

One report, multiple pages depending on the parameter/data. It's not a 3 different reports solutions, but something that *could* work for your situation.